# How to call the sub function into the main function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Apps Script

```
function Docs() {

  this.getActions = function(p) {

  console.log("get action calling")

  }
```

I need to call the getActions function in Docs funtion

Comment: `this.getActions()`?

Comment: Appscript or Google Apps Script? They are different...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function Docs() {

  this.getActions = function(p) {
    Logger.log("get action calling")
  }

  this.callActions = function () {
    this.getActions();    
  }
}

function test() {
  var docs;
  docs = new Docs();

  docs.getActions();
  docs.callActions();
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22049454)

Comment: @Nick i thought it was self explaining and doesn't need some extra words will make sure for future answer to put them in context.